# Where do Gamers visit in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, culture

Ok, I'm a huge gamer and of course a SEGA fan (played Sonic the Hedgehog since '93) and I be travelling to Japan in December. Any place in Tokyo I can fulfil the inner child in me? Looking for followings:

**Place to Play For Adults**: First of all, a place I can go and play retro games of the early 90s mainly (e.g., Mortal Combat, Sonic, etc.) and of course like to play new generation games as well, like FPS genre. Any futuristic place I can find that I can't find anywhere else?

**'The Mecca' For Gamers**: Any place that plays any significance part in computer games history, that I can visit?

**Any 'Tour' I can take?**: Is there any tour I can take in any game studio of past or present?

**Any Disneyland-like Park**: Any park I can visit that does have the Nintendo/Sega/Playstation characters?

Comment: What do you want in fact?

Comment: @Him I want to play! 0_o

Comment: Unrelated, but you might also like Osaka's Den Den Town (Nipponbashi). Lots of anime, otaku, animation, electronics stuff there not to mention tons of arcades

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a few game hubs in Tokyo, but Akihabara is the classic techy gamer paradise. Plenty of new and used game stores, arcades and curious little shops. In particular:

- **Super Potato**, on the upper floors of a back alley building off the main strip. A veritable treasure trove of vintage video games (Nintendo, Sega, Sony plus weird and wonderful platforms you've never heard of). Lots of rare machines and games too (including a working Virtual Boy). See [their website](http://www.superpotato.com) for more info.
- The **Sega Arcades** (8 floor one in Akiba) - 8 floors of UFO catchers, fighting machines, shooters, the works). Take the Electric Town exit from JR Akihabara station and you can't miss it
- The **[TRADER](http://aki-on.com/eng/hobby/h-allinone/977/)** chain of shops - 5 in all in Akiba, with lots of rare / used games going back to PS1 days. TRADER 4 is probably the best one, but they're all full of interesting odds and sods.
- **Yodobashi Akiba** - a mammoth electronics department store with a massive floor dedicated to recent platforms / hardware / software. A giant version of your usual Gamestops / GAMEs. It's on the other side of Akihabara station from Electric Town, and is [so large you'd struggle to miss it](http://www.yodobashi.com/ec/store/0018/index.html).

For more stores see this [great Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2012/feb/01/top-10-video-games-shops-tokyo).

If you are over 20 there are also lots of cool video game bars to try out. There's a good few in this [GamesRadar](http://www.gamesradar.com/tokyos-underground-game-bars/) article.

Of these, I've visited **8 Bit Cafe in Shinjuku** - suitable for nerds and non-nerds alike, with a comically large cocktail menu, each entry based on some video game (the Dr Mario one in a beaker with gel pills is excellent). See [their website (in Japanese)](http://8bitcafe.net/index.html) for more details. They're based at Shinjuku 3-8-9, Shinjuku Q Building 5F (it's a bit of a nightmare to find, but the linked article has some good images to find the exact stairwell to traverse).

I should add, for the bars, some of them are video game themed, but not necessarily what we would consider 'gaming cafes' (i.e. you can drink but it's not a place for playing games).

If you fancy a futuristic theme park experience, try the incredible **Joyopolis** in Odaiba. A massive indoor theme park made by Sega with incredible rides (real rally cars playing Sega Rally, a House of the Dead roller coaster), a big arcade, Sega-franchise exclusive arcade machines, and a general all-round "this is insane" vibe. See http://tokyo-joypolis.com/language/english/. It's at DECKS Tokyo Beach, 1−6−1 Odaiba, Minato, postcode 135-0091.

Of course, if you're a real pilgrim you could get pictures outside the **Square Enix office** in [east Shinjuku](http://www.jp.square-enix.com/company/en/access/index2.html) and the **Nintendo office** in [Asakusabashi](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/corporate/en/offices/index.html) (5-21-5 Asakusabashi, Taito-ku, Tokyo 111-0053).

If you've anything specific in mind though leave a note in the comments and I can have a think.

**Update** - If you have an international drivers permit you can also do real life **Mario Kart** around the streets of Tokyo, which is probably about as gamer-cool as it gets. Find out more at [the booking page](https://www.govoyagin.com/activities/japan-tokyo-rent-go-karts-and-ride-around-akihabara/2534)

You might also be interested in taking a tour of the **Sony Building** in Ginza - it's more than just games, but they usually have a cool selection of the latest Playstation games, gadgets and gizmos, as well as a mini-cinema that sometimes features games / trailer. Take a look at the Sony Building [English website](http://www.sonybuilding.jp/e/).

Comment: Oh man, thanks for the time and input. I be trying to go to all these places.

Comment: No worries, hope you have a great time!